# Using boost::mpl::find_if with custom predicate

Tags: c++, type-traits, boost-mpl

Given

```
struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {C(B) {}};
struct D : B {};
struct E {operator A() const {return A();}};
struct F {};

using AllowedTypes = boost::mpl::vector<A, C>;
```

I'm trying to implement a predicate `is_allowed_type` so that

```
static_assert(is_allowed_type<A>::value, "A is in AllowedTypes");
static_assert(is_allowed_type<B>::value, "C is constructible from B");
static_assert(is_allowed_type<C>::value, "C is in AllowedTypes");
static_assert(is_allowed_type<D>::value, "D inherits from B, from which C is constructible");
static_assert(is_allowed_type<E>::value, "E is convertible to A");
static_assert(!is_allowed_type<F>::value, "F is not convertible to A nor C");
```

The predicate must return true iff its argument is convertible to one of the types in `AllowedTypes`.

Here is what I have come up with.

```
template <typename T>
struct is_allowed_type
{
    using I = boost::mpl::find_if<AllowedTypes, std::is_convertible<T, boost::mpl::_>>;
    using End = boost::mpl::end<AllowedTypes>;
    enum {value = !std::is_same<I, End>::value};
};
```

The last assertion fails. What is wrong with my `is_allowed_type`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer while writing the question but since I had difficulties to find material on the subject I am posting it.

The iterator definitions in `is_allowed_type` are missing `::type`. The correct implementation is

```
template <typename T>
struct is_allowed_type
{
    using I = typename boost::mpl::find_if<AllowedTypes, std::is_convertible<T, boost::mpl::_>>::type;
    using End = typename boost::mpl::end<AllowedTypes>::type;
    enum {value = !std::is_same<I, End>::value};
};
```

Comment: Anyway I still don't understand how placeholders like `boost::mpl::_` can work with metafunctions that are not designed specifically for them, like `std::is_convertible`... How does it happen that `std::is_convertible<T, boost::mpl::_>` is not evaluated immediately, resulting in a constant? Could someone explain?

Comment: It is like black magic, right? Anyway, MPL is quite hard to read, write, and reason about. Consider [Boost.Hana](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html) as the way forward in C++ metaprogramming since it doesn't require everything to exist solely in templates -- "We need more metaprogramming but less _template_ metaprogramming." See Louis Dionne's [ACCU talk](https://youtu.be/Oc4enqNH-Mc) ([slides](http://ldionne.github.io/accu-2017-metaprogramming-in-cpp14)) or his [other talks](http://ldionne.com/talks/).

Comment: Wow, I had never heard/read of Boost.Hana. This new approach is really interesting but I wonder why Boost folks, whose many belong to the C++ standardization committee, are still exploring library-based metaprogramming approaches rather than language-embedded new features.

Comment: Simple -- MPL (and Boost.Fusion, which is another precursor to Hana) works in C++03, whereas Hana requires C++11/14. Metaprogramming before C++11 had to use something like MPL. While existing code bases may still need to maintain existing MPL code and new code bases stuck with older compilers (e.g., gcc 5.x) may have to use MPL where metaprogramming is required, but there is a better way now if you've got a more recent compiler. Huzzah!